# Verify that a user is logged in using .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, .net-3.5

I have the following code in my code behind:

```
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
 {    
     bool status = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

My username and password validate correctly, but the status is always false. How do I actually login the user to make status true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create auth cookie first

```
if(Membership.ValidateUser(username,password))
{
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username,true); 
} //do it in login page
```

Then you can check if user is authenticated, before you can't know that, because website is stateless

Comment: does the authcookie get set right away? like can i call isauthenticated on the next line, cause it still gives me false

Comment: @chris afaik it won't be available in that request, because information will go after redirection, you can use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage for e.g. or whatever other redirect

Answer (score 0):

From the method's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) in MSDN:

> ValidateUser provides an easy way to verify a user name and password
>   from the data source

Note that it doesn't actually log in your user, it just tells you if the user name/password pair is correct or not. To actually create an authentication cookie for your user you need to use [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).